# VS19 C# only one Font class constructors given

Tags: c#, system.drawing

my `Font` class (needed for string width calculation in a Unity scripts) only shows the `{string name}` constructor and therefore can't be initialized with a `fontSize` argument

I've added the `System.Drawing` to my References, tried `using System.Drawing` and use .NET Framework 4.7.2

I haven't found any even remotely similar problem on Google yet

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure your `Font` is actually `System.Drawing.Font`. Do this by using the fully qualified name `new System.Drawing.Font(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Wiktor! VS is only allowing me to use the `System.Drawing` but not further than that, it only offers `Color, Point, PointF, Rectangle, RectangleF, Size, SizeF` as options

Comment: Sounds like you added a nuget package instead of using the framework reference.

Comment: Hi Hans! I just checked at Project->Manage NuGet Packages and both Installed and Update are empty. Could you please point me to what you are referring to as I haven't used NuGet yet

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got the answer:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/unity-scripting-upgrade?view=vs-2019]

I've had Unity use the **2.x Api Compatibility Level**

Changed it via

> Edit->Project Settings->Player->Api Compatibility Level

Set it to `.NET 4.x`

Import the latest Reference `.dll`

Thanks for the help!